# Ayuda para conectarme a una base de datos

Tags: php, c#

estoy intentando conectar mi programa de c# a una base de datos alojada en un servidor web llamado awardspace, pero no logro completar la conexión, me sale el siguiente error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

el método que estoy usando el siguiente:

```
MySqlConnection conectar = new MySqlConnection("server=pdb46.awardspace.net;database=********; 
username=********; password=*******; port=****;");
```

Mi amigo que programa en php puede conectarse sin ningún problema, el usa el siguiente método:

```
<?php
$hostname='pdb46.awardspace.net';
$database='*******';
$username='*******';
$password='*******';

$conexion=new mysqli($hotname,$username,$password,$database);
if($conexion->connect_errno){
    echo "El sitio web está experimentando problemas";
}
?>
```

Entonces, si alguien pudiera ayudarme a conectarme, se lo agradecería

---

Ya se soluciono el problema, emplee un archivo de conexión php desde dentro del servidor y lo llame a mi programa

Comment: duplicaste la pregunta.

Comment: No te falta abrir la conexion?

Comment: La forma correcta seria que hagas una API Rest y la consumas desde C#, podrias usa httpwebrequest

Answer (score 2):

La [cadena de conexión para Mysql](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) tiene el formato siguiente:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Si te fijas, en vez de `username` y `password` debes usar `uid` y `pwd`.Así que debes cambiar tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
MySqlConnection conectar = new MySqlConnection("server=pdb46.awardspace.net;database=********; Uid=********; Pwd=*******; port=****;");
```